# OpenSceneGraph: analysing a scenegraph

Tags: c++, opengl, openscenegraph

I want to read a 3D Model through OSG and learn the 3D model information about vertices, normals and texture coordinates etc.

I do not understand the code below ([complete tutorial from here](http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/documentation/tutorials/72-analysing-a-scenegraph) ). why are we using `prset->index(ic)` as an index? I am confused. `(* verts)` is the vertex array but what is the `prset->index(ic)` ?

```
for (ic=0; ic<prset->getNumIndices(); ic++) { // NB the vertices are held in the drawable -
    osg::notify(osg::WARN) << "vertex "<< ic << " is index "<<prset->index(ic) << " at " <<
        (* verts)[prset->index(ic)].x() << "," <<
        (* verts)[prset->index(ic)].y() << "," << 
        (* verts)[prset->index(ic)].z() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your drawable uses indexed primitives, you need to de-reference the triangle vertices looking into the indices array, as you might re-use shared vertices of the vertex array.
Something like [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/#the-principle-of-indexing).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually I dont know how to get indices array from a drawable or a geometry. Any idea for it ?

Comment: The answer is in the code you posted: you get the ic-th index from the PrimitiveSet with `prset->index(ic)` and use such index to access the corresponding vertex in the vertex array

Comment: Oh thanks I just got it. I was using right indices but making some other mistake because of de-referencing. Now, I used like this for GL_TRIANGLES:
 'tri.a=prset->index(i2)'  , 'tri.b=prset->index(i2+1)'  and 'tri.c=prset->index(i2+2)'